# How to call DATE_CHANGED action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created a broadcast receiver that should run when date changes, but it does not work when I change date of my phone. But when I change action to Change time zone, it works fine. I change phone's time zone and it runs perfectly. How should I test DATE_CHANGED action?

this is how did I add the Broadcast receiver in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".service.CheckVersionBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This is my Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class CheckVersionBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    CheckVersion checkVersion;
    String latestVersion;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkVersion = new CheckVersion();
        try {
            latestVersion = checkVersion.execute().get();
            Toast.makeText(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext,latestVersion,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(!latestVersion.equals(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)){
                ApplicationLoader loader = new ApplicationLoader();
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                loader.setUpNotification(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext,when);
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try {

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date strDate = sdf.parse(date1);
            String sDate1 = date2;
            Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(sDate1);

            if (date1.after(strDate)) {}
}catch(exception e){
}
```

Comment: where should I add this code? What is date1 and date2? Where did you declare them?